# Unable to drain/cancel Dataflow job. It keeps pending state

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Some jobs are remaining with pending pending state and I can't cancel them.

How do I cancel the job.

Web console shows like this.

- "The graph is still being analyzed."
- All logs  are "No entries found matching current filter."
- Job status: "Starting..."
  There isn't appered  a cancel button yet.

There are no instances in the Compute Engline tab.

What I did is below.
I created a streaming job. it was simple template job, Pubsub subscription to BigQuery. I set machineType as e2-micro because it was just a testing.

I also tried to drain and cancel by gcloud but it doesn't work.

```
$ gcloud dataflow jobs drain --region asia-northeast1 JOBID

Failed to drain job [...]: (...): Workflow modification failed. Causes: (...): 
Operation drain not allowed for JOBID. 
Job is not yet ready for draining. Please retry in a few minutes. 
Please ensure you have permission to access the job and the `--region` flag, asia-northeast1, matches the job's
region.
```

This is jobs list

```
$ gcloud dataflow jobs list --region asia-northeast1
JOB_ID  NAME                               TYPE       CREATION_TIME        STATE      REGION
JOBID1  pubsub-to-bigquery-udf4            Streaming  2021-02-09 04:24:23  Pending    asia-northeast1
JOBID2  pubsub-to-bigquery-udf2            Streaming  2021-02-09 03:20:35  Pending    asia-northeast1
...other jobs...
```

Please let me know how to stop/cancel/delete these streaming jobs.

Job IDs:

- 2021-02-08_20_24_22-11667100055733179687
- 2021-02-08_20_24_22-11667100055733179687

WebUI:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B75OX.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzUGQ.png

Comment: How about this command? https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/cancel

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've already done the cancel command but it's same as drain.

Comment: Have you tried to stop the job from Dataflow UI in GCP?

Comment: There isn't appeared stop button on the Dataflow UI yet. So I couldn't use the button yet. https://i.stack.imgur.com/B75OX.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per personal experience some time few instance get stuck either they keep on running, or they cannot be canceled  or you can not see thr graphical data flow pipelines. Best way to handle this kind of issue is to leave them in thr status, unless it is not impacting your solution by exceeding maximum concurrent runs at a moment. It will be canceled automatically or by Google team, since Dataflow is a  google managed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see. I wait it will be canceled by the google team. The jobs are still stuck for 48 hours. Fortunately, the job doesn't seem to cost anything according to my billing. so I just wait.

Comment: Finally, The jobs were stopped as status "Failed" after 6 days passed. Thank you. https://imgur.com/a/MbSZqur

Comment: Does it indicate any failure reason over Job logs ?

Comment: It shows "Worker machine type has insufficient memory to support this type of Dataflow job." Yes, I set machine type as e2-micro. Probably, It seems too small. I think GCP DataFlow should reject to start of this machine type.

Answer (score 0):

In GCP console Dataflow UI, if you have running Dataflow jobs, you will see the "STOP" button just like the below image.

[image]

Press the STOP button.
[image]

When you successfully stop your job, you will see the status like below. (I was too slow to stop the job with the first try, so I had to test it again. :) )
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know how to stop the job. I usually stop the job like you show.
In my case, After I start the job, it keeps the state "starting..."
I mean the job doesn't start properly, it doesn't run and I can't stop the job. The job is stuck in the "starting..." state for more than 1 day. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzUGQ.png

Comment: @tsbm So your jobs doesn't start and get stuck in "pending" state forever. right?

Comment: @tsbm I hope Google will take care of your problems soon. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, jobs get stack in “pending” state forever. I’m sorry for my English. Thank you.